# Make a autofill date script only function on 1 sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script running on a sheet which works perfectly, however, I need it to only function on 1 sheet and not all of them. How do I go about that? The sheet it should work on is called 'SocialMediaSchedule'

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if ([5, 7, 9].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("d mmm yy");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to run the script of `onEdit()` for only the sheet with the sheet name of `SocialMediaSchedule`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- You can retrieve the sheet name by `e.source.getSheetName()`.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getSheetName() == "SocialMediaSchedule" && [5, 7, 9].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("d mmm yy");
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetname)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @user10637952 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.